# How can the pushing view cover the tabbar in wix/react-native-navigation for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

How can I cover the tab bar by pushing a new view in [Wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/) for react native?

I can push new views with the API but I can't find any method that is able to push with covering the tab bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new screen you are pushing, add `tabBarHidden: true` to the `navigatorStyle`.

```
class NextScreen extends Component {
  static navigatorStyle = {
    tabBarHidden: true,
    drawUnderTabBar: true // Since we want to render the screen instead of the tabBar
  };
}
```

More styling options can be found in the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/styling-the-navigator?id=style-object-format)

Comment: Thank you so much!